# Unable to locate element error retrieving text value of class variable

Tags: python, selenium, element

I am trying to grab the value of the version info, 1.0, in this case.

If I right click and Inspect Element, I see the following:

```
<span class="ng-binding" ng-bind="$ctrl.Version">1.0</span>
```

If I copy CSS Selector in Firefox, it shows me the following:

```
.version-numbers > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(2)
```

I am trying the following Python code:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".version-numbers[value='$ctrl.backendVersion']").text)
```

I haven't been able to get it to work with XPath either. I get an Unable to locate Element error.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you show the url?

Comment: It seems like you are passing the xpath to `find_element_by_css_selector` (instead of the css selector above)?

Answer (score 0):

As per the given *HTML* to retrieve the text **1.0** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* with `expected_conditions` clause as `visibility_of_element_located` and you can use the following line of code :

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ng-binding']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I used CSS Selector and it appears to be working now.  Thank you for your suggestions.